# Xcode 10 Not supporting Subversion **[SVN]**

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, xcode10

I have updated the XCode 10 on two days before (19 sep'17) before.

Its not showing the Source Control in my all project. Its working fine in Xcode 9.4 and old.

Any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [Xcode 10 release note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes?language=objc). 
In the Deprecation Notice, they stated:

```
Support for Subversion has been removed. (33361671)
```